# Obtain Private Key Corresponding to Address in HD Wallet with BlockCypher API?

Tags: cryptography, blockchain, bitcoin, cryptocurrency

We are using BlockCypher API to [create transaction](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin/#creating-transactions) in a [HD Wallet](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin/#hierarchical-deterministic-hd-wallets).

> As a return object, you'll receive a TXSkeleton containing a
> slightly-more complete TX alongside data you need to sign in the
> tosign array. You'll need this object for the next steps of the
> transaction creation process.

> **Locally Sign Your Transaction**
>
> With your TXSkeleton returned from the New Transaction Endpoint, you
> now need to use your private key(s) to sign the data provided in the
> **tosign** array.

> *$PRIVATEKEY here is a hex-encoded private key corresponding to the input from address CEztKBAYNoUEEaPYbkyFeXC5v8Jz9RoZH9*

My problem is how do we obtain the private key of each address in HD Wallet? With HD Wallet addresses are generated using the [Derive Address Endpoint](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin/?shell#derive-address-in-wallet-endpoint). This returns a [HDWallet object](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin/?shell#hdwallet) which contains and [HDChain object](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin/?shell#hdchain) which contains an [HDAddress Object](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin/?shell#hdaddress). The HDAddress object contains address, path and public.

> An HD Address object contains an address and its BIP32 HD path
> (location of the address in the HD tree). It also contains the
> hex-encoded public key when returned from the Derive Address in Wallet
> endpoint.

As you can see, the private key is not included in `HDAddress` object response. So how can we know the private key to use with **`tosign`** method if the private key is not included in `HDAddress` object response? And without access to private key, how can we sign the `**tosign**` array?

Thanks

Comment: From my personal experience with Blockcypher, they don't answer emails. I dont know why they do this

Comment: have you come up with any solution